# what is this wall box/bracket for?

Tags: cabling, home-theater

I recently moved into a townhome.  The living room appears to be wired for surround sound.  Where the satellite speakers would go, there are blank wall plates.

Behind two of the wall plates are boxes/brackets as shown below (you can see the gray speaker wire running up behind it).

What is this type of bracket intended for?  It looks like something is meant to fit inside the semi-circular openings, or perhaps they are supposed to bent away? I haven't been able to find anything similar online.

[image: wall box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an Erico MP1S bracket.  Used for low voltage wiring, the tabs can be bent back and 3/4 conduit attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

The bracket you have is meant to hold a finish wall plate over the opening that low voltage wiring can or will pass through. You can bend back the tabs you refer to, I presume it is to hold the cabling so it makes a better turn out through the face plate.